# Angular ContentChild

Tags: angular

I've got a problem and I don't find the failure.
Im trying to use ContentChild in Angular.
Ive created 2 Components `(BlogEntries, BlogEntry)` a module which knows these and imported that module to the Main Component app.component.

`BlogEntries` uses `BlogEntry` as a ChildContent. In the BlogEntries Template I've set the `<ng-content></ng-content>` Element.

When im starting the application.
The Stuff from BlogEntries is shown but not that from the Contentchild BlogEntry.

Hopefully someone can help me.

AppModule:-

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BlogentriesModule } from './blogentries/blogentries.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BlogentriesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

AppComponent Template

```
<wr-blog-blogentries></wr-blog-blogentries>
```

BlogEntries Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BlogentriesComponent } from './blogentries.component';
import { BlogentryComponent } from './blogentry/blogentry.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [BlogentriesComponent, BlogentryComponent],
  exports: [BlogentriesComponent]
})
export class BlogentriesModule {

}
```

BlogEntries Component

```
import { Component, ContentChild, OnInit, AfterContentInit, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { BlogentryComponent } from './blogentry/blogentry.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'wr-blog-blogentries',
  templateUrl: './blogentries.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blogentries.component.css']
})
export class BlogentriesComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(BlogentryComponent) blogentry: BlogentryComponent;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(`ngAfterContentInit - blogentry is ${this.blogentry}`);
  }

}
```

BlogEntries Template

```
<p>
  blogentries works!
</p>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

BlogEntry Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'wr-blog-blogentry',
  templateUrl: './blogentry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./blogentry.component.css'],
})
export class BlogentryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

BlogEntry Template

```
<div>
  Blog Entry
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `@ContentChild(BlogEntry)` to work you would need to pass content

```html
<wr-blog-blogentries>
  <wr-blog-blogentry></wr-blog-blogentry>
</wr-blog-blogentries>
```

Comment: Zöchbauer: Ive seen samples of using ContentChild in which nothing is passed or am I wrong, like this one: https://embed.plnkr.co/rSmStf53EZx4Dh4AlI1g/

Comment: `<my-child>` is passed the same way I showed in my answer `<my-parent>
           <my-child></my-child>
        </my-parent>`

Comment: Ah sry ur code block wasn't visible after reloading the page I've seen it now. Thanks for ur help.

Comment: I see. I didn't indent the code far enough at first and updated it a few seconds later. You were just too fast ;-). Glad to hear you figured it out.